# Server-side Pagination in Sails with DataTables

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, sails.js, waterline

I am currently using the server-side option of DataTables, my current problem is that the page numbers in the data table only displays 1. To further explain here is my code:

Javascript:

```
var oTable1 = $('#users-table').dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/v1/users",
    "bPaginate": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "username" },
        { "mData": "name" },
        { "mData": "acctype" },
        { "mData": "country" },
        { "mData": "createdAt" },
        { "mData": "button" }
    ]
});
```

/v1/users:

```
viewAll: function(req, res, next) {

    var colS = "";

    switch(req.query.iSortCol_0){
        case '0': colS = 'id'; break;
        case '1': colS = 'username'; break;
        case '2': colS = 'firstname'; break;
        case '3': colS = 'acctype'; break;
        case '4': colS = 'country'; break;
        case '5': colS = 'createdAt'; break;
        default: break;
    };

    var options = {
        sort: colS+' '+req.query.sSortDir_0,
        or: [
            { acctype: { 'contains': req.query.sSearch }},
            { id: { 'contains': req.query.sSearch }},
            { username: { 'contains': req.query.sSearch }},
            { lastname: { 'contains': req.query.sSearch }},
            { firstname: { 'contains': req.query.sSearch }},
            { country: { 'contains': req.query.sSearch }},
            { createdAt: { 'contains': req.query.sSearch }}
        ],
        limit: req.query.iDisplayLength
    };

    console.log(req.query);
    console.log(req.query.sSearch);
    //console.log(options);
    var p = req.query.iDisplayStart+1;

    //console.log(req.query.iDisplayStart);
    Users.find(options).paginate({ page: p, limit: req.query.iDisplayLength }).exec(function(err, usr){
        if(err){
            res.send(500, { error: 'DB error' });
        } else {
            var retuser = [];
            usr.forEach(function(user){
                retuser.push({ id: user.id, username: user.username, name: user.firstname+" "+user.lastname, acctype: user.acctype, country: user.country, createdAt: user.createdAt, button: "<a class='blue' href='#view-user' data-toggle='modal' id='user-info'> <i class='icon-zoom-in bigger-130'></i></a>" });
            });

            Users.count().exec(function(err, result){
                var json = {
                    aaData: retuser,
                    iTotalRecords: result,
                    iTotalDisplayRecords: usr.length
                };
                res.contentType('application/json');
                res.json(json);
            });
        }
    });
},
```

What basically happens is that: 
 When I change the page in

> .paginate({ page: p, limit: req.query.iDisplayLength })

to 2, it shows what should be displayed in page 2, and if I change it to 1, it shows what should be displayed in page 1. And when change the number of records to display, it shows the 11th record. So I guess there is no problem with regards to how I retrieve my data from the controller.

I thought that DataTables automatically adds page numbers based on the `iTotalDisplayRecords` and `iTotalRecords`, but it turns out that it isn't. Is there something wrong with my code or what I thought was wrong, that I'd have to be the one to add the page numbers in my DataTable?

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: You can work with this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-datatable. Its straightforward and easy to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're returning wrong value in `iTotalDisplayRecords`:

```
"iTotalRecords": 11, 
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 10
```

From the [manual](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side):

> int   `iTotalRecords`
>   Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total
>   number of records in the database)
>
> int   `iTotalDisplayRecords`
>   Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after
>   filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being
>   returned in this result set)

When filtering is not performed, `iTotalRecords` should be equal to `iTotalDisplayRecords`.

To correct the problem, you need to calculate **total number of records** after filtering has been applied and use that value for `iTotalDisplayRecords` instead of `usr.length`.

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood what was stated on the documentation. I thought the filtering that was mentioned includes the limit that I set.